# how to iterate over this attributes in jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

In view method, i do this:

```
 for i in range(0,15):
       setattr(object, 'f%d' % i, 'abc')
```

So now i have attributes f1, f2,f3,f4,f5.
Then how can i iterate over it in jinja2 template?

Something like this, or i dont know:

```
 {%for i in range(0,15)%}
   {{f}}i
{%endfor%}
```

**EDIT:**
in view method, form['select%d'|format(i)] doesnt work, but in template it does

```
def method():       
class F(Form):
    pass
count=0

for attempt in e.attempts_of_exam:
    setattr(F, 'select%d'%count, SelectField(attempt.attempter.username,
                                    validators=[validators.optional()],
                                    choices=[('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'),
                                     ('D', 'D'), ('E', 'E'), ('FX', 'FX'),
                                     ('n/a', 'n/a')]))
    count +=1

form = F()
i =0
if form.validate_on_submit():
    for attempt in e.attempts_of_exam:
        attempt.result = form['select%d'|format(i)].data
        i +=1
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('attempts_of_exam',id=e.id))


else:
    return render_template('update_exam_results.html',
        form=form,
        count=count,
        exam = e)
```

and then in template

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <table border='1'>
            {% for i in range(count) %}
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    {{ form['select%d'|format(i)].label}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form['select%d'|format(i)]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Why not use a list? How is `object` available in the template?

Comment: i sent that object to template via render_template('a.html',object=object)

Comment: Do you want to render *just* the select fields? You can just loop over the form and get *all* fields.

Comment: i want to render select fields and their labels, as shown above. Can you show me how to loop over form? Or i can do 'for f in form' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use item access:

```html
{% for i in range(15) %}
    {{ object['f%d'|format(i)] }}
{% endfor %}
```

but you'd be better off just using a list instead.

For forms, just loop over the form object:

```html
{% for field in form %}
    <td>
        {{ field.label }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ field }}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

In your view, you can access the results in the `form.data` object; this is just a dictionary:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    for i, attempt in enumerate(e.attempts_of_exam):
        attempt.result = form.data['select%d' % i]
```

Comment: i ll send full code in separate answer, cause i dont know how to use it with list... what i m trying to do is something bigger ...

Comment: @user3263155: put that in your question instead. What form library is this?

Comment: wtforms library , im trying to do Dynamic Form Composition

Comment: it works with item acces in jinja2 like u said, but now i have problem how to iterate it in python view method, after it has been created...

Comment: yay, thank u, this worked :D , can u explain what that last for loop in python does? i have known only simple ones like 'for i in x'

Comment: It uses the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add a loop counter. It's just like your loop but you don't need to do `i = 0` and `i += 1`; tuples of `(counter, original_value)` are produced instead.

Comment: The concept you missed there is that you can just generate `select%d` keys in Python too.

Answer (score 0):

in view method, form['select%d'|format(i)] doesnt work, but in template it does

```
def method():       
class F(Form):
    pass
count=0

for attempt in e.attempts_of_exam:
    setattr(F, 'select%d'%count, SelectField(attempt.attempter.username,
                                    validators=[validators.optional()],
                                    choices=[('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'),
                                     ('D', 'D'), ('E', 'E'), ('FX', 'FX'),
                                     ('n/a', 'n/a')]))
    count +=1

form = F()
i =0
if form.validate_on_submit():
    for attempt in e.attempts_of_exam:
        attempt.result = form['select%d'|format(i)].data
        i +=1
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('attempts_of_exam',id=e.id))


else:
    return render_template('update_exam_results.html',
        form=form,
        count=count,
        exam = e)
```

and then in template

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <table border='1'>
            {% for i in range(count) %}
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    {{ form['select%d'|format(i)].label}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form['select%d'|format(i)]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.